# Me marca indefinido la referencia a la vtable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

**Marca referencia indefinida en v table**
Hice una clase padre, que es vehículos, el cual es heredado por dos clases hija.
Cuando no incluyo las clases hijas el programa compila y genera el *.exe.
Pero cuando incluyo las dos clases hijas manda este error:
*(.text$*ZN9VehiculosC2EPcS0_S0_S0_S0*[_*ZN9VehiculosC2EPcS0_S0_S0_S0*]+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for Vehiculos'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status*
Ya busque e hice de nuevo mi código, pero aun así me marca error. 
**Esta es mi clase padre:**

```
#ifndef __VEHICULOS_H__

#define __VEHICULOS_H__

class Vehiculos
{
protected:
    char *nombreCom;
    char *nombreP;
    char *origen;
    char *destino;
    char *FechaS;
    long double CostoTotal;

public:
    Vehiculos(char *nombreCom, char *nombreP, char *origen, char *destino, char *FechaS)
    {
        this->nombreCom = nombreCom;
        this->nombreP = nombreP;
        this->origen = origen;
        this->destino = destino;
        this->FechaS = FechaS;
        this->CostoTotal = 0;
    };
    virtual long double CalcularPresioTotal(float);
};

#endif
```

**Estas son mis clases hijas:**

```
#ifndef __TAXI_H__
#define __TAXI_H__

#include "Vehiculos.h"

class Taxi : public Vehiculos
{
private:
    char *matricula;

public:
    Taxi(char *);
    ~Taxi();
    long double CalcularPresioTotal(float);
};
Taxi::Taxi(char *matricula) : Vehiculos(nombreCom, nombreP, origen, destino, FechaS)
{
    this->matricula = matricula;
}

Taxi::~Taxi()
{
}
long double Taxi::CalcularPresioTotal(float kmrecorridos)
{
    this->CostoTotal = kmrecorridos * 1;
    return (this->CostoTotal += 20);
}
#endif

#ifndef __AVION_H__

#define __AVION_H__

#include "Vehiculos.h"

enum Categorys
{
    PrimeraClase = 1,
    ClaseTurusta = 2
};

class Avion : public Vehiculos
{
private:
    char *NumV = new char[6];
    char *asiento = new char[2];
    Categorys categoria;

public:
    Avion(char *, char *, Categorys);

    ~Avion();
    long double CalcularPresioTotal(float);
};
Avion::Avion(char *NumV, char *asiento, Categorys categoria) : Vehiculos(nombreCom, nombreP, origen, destino, FechaS)
{
    this->NumV = NumV;
    this->asiento = asiento;
    this->categoria = categoria;
}

Avion::~Avion()
{
}
long double Avion::CalcularPresioTotal(float kmrecorridos)
{
    this->CostoTotal = kmrecorridos * 3;
    return (this->CostoTotal += this->CostoTotal);
}
#endif

#ifndef __AUTOMOVIL_H__
#define __AUTOMOVIL_H__

#include "Vehiculos.h"

enum TypePasangers
{
    nino = 1,
    adulto = 2,
    mayor = 3
};

class Autobus : Vehiculos
{
private:
    TypePasangers tipoDePasagero;
    int NumAsiento;

public:
    Autobus(TypePasangers, int);
    ~Autobus();
    long double CalcularPresioTotal(float);
};

Autobus::Autobus(TypePasangers tipoDePasagero, int NumAsiento) : Vehiculos(nombreCom, nombreP, origen, destino, FechaS)
{
    this->tipoDePasagero = tipoDePasagero;
    this->NumAsiento = NumAsiento;
}

Autobus::~Autobus()
{
}

long double Autobus::CalcularPresioTotal(float kmRecorridos)
{
    if (this->tipoDePasagero == TypePasangers::mayor)
    {
        this->CostoTotal = (kmRecorridos * 2) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        this->CostoTotal = kmRecorridos * 2;
    }
    return this->CostoTotal;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Ese error es **de enlazado**. Eso quiere decir que tu programa compila bien, pero falla en el siguiente paso, al construir el ejecutable. ¿ Como **exactamente** lo estás compilando ?

Comment: Estoy usando el debugger de code, con mingW, usa el g++.
Aveces yo pongo este codigo `g++ -o main main.cpp`.
La version de mingW es 8.1.0

Comment: La compilación son dos pasos: compilación y enlazado, en el enlazado tienes que referenciar todo el código objeto que has generado en la compilación (todos los .o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un pequeño error que estás cometiendo:

En C++, cuando trabajes con clases virtuales y herencia, asegúrate que los destructores de las clases padre son **virtuales**.

Si no es así y usas polimorfismo acabarás inevitablemente con fugas de memoria:

```
class Vehiculos
{
public:
    virtual ~Vehiculos() = default;
};
```

Es facil demostrar el problema que se crea si se te olvida este detalle:

```
class Mal1
{
public:
    ~Mal1()
    { std::cout << "Este destructor no se invoca nunca!!!\n"; }
};

class Mal2 : public Mal1
{
public:
    ~Mal2()
    { std::cout << "Mal2::~Mal2()\n"; }
};

class Bien1
{
public:
    virtual ~Bien1()
    { std::cout << "Bien1::~Bien1()\n"; }
};

class Bien2 : public Bien1
{
public:
    ~Bien2()
    { std::cout << "Bien2::~Bien2()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Mal1 * mal = new Mal2;
    delete mal;

    Bien1 * bien = new Bien2;
    delete bien;
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lWLdilgVWAYaETA8)

En cualquier caso tu problema es, como te estamos diciendo, que durante la fase de enlazado no estás referenciando todos los archivos de código objeto:

```
g++ -o app main.o Autobus.o Avion.o Taxi.o Vehiculos.o
```

Fíjate que los archivos de los que dependen los demás van al final

```
g++ -o app [más dependencias] ... [sin dependencias]
```

Comment: Ya genere mi destructor y aun asi sigue mandando el mismo error, tambien estoy poniendo todos los archivos  _g++ -o main main.cpp models/Vehiculos.h models/Autobus.h models/Avion.h models/Taxi.h_  
Y me manda esto:  **C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsKO4HD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN9VehiculosC2EPcS0_S0_S0_S0_[__ZN9VehiculosC2EPcS0_S0_S0_S0_]+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for Vehiculos'
C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsKO4HD.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN9VehiculosD2Ev[__ZN9VehiculosD2Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for Vehiculos'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**